# FIlter a value from stdout_lines of Ansible output below

Tags: filter, ansible

I would like to FIlter  value of Endpoint from stdout_lines of Ansible output below:

```
            "{", 
            "    \"DBCluster\": {", 
            "        \"MasterUsername\": \"mstrusr\", ", 
            "        \"ReaderEndpoint\": \"tstng4.cluster-ro-czzpyhxnqlzh.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com\", ", 
            "        \"VpcSecurityGroups\": [", 
            "            {", 
            "                \"Status\": \"active\", ", 
            "                \"VpcSecurityGroupId\": \"sg-xxx5677\"", 
            "            }", 
            "        ], ", 
            "        \"HostedZoneId\": \"ZNKXH85TT8WVW\", ", 
            "        \"Status\": \"creating\", ", 
            "        \"MultiAZ\": false, ", 
            "        \"PreferredBackupWindow\": \"03:51-04:21\", ", 
            "        \"DBSubnetGroup\": \"subnet\", ", 
            "        \"BackupRetentionPeriod\": 1, ", 
            "        \"PreferredMaintenanceWindow\": \"mon:05:00-mon:05:30\", ", 
            "        \"Engine\": \"docdb\", ", 
            "        \"Endpoint\": \"tstng4.cluster-czzpyhxnqlzh.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com\", ", 
            "        \"ClusterCreateTime\": \"2020-01-23T10:06:44.338Z\", ", 
            "        \"EngineVersion\": \"3.6.0\", ", 
            "        \"DeletionProtection\": true, ", 
            "        \"DBClusterIdentifier\": \"vce-docdb-tst4\", ", 
            "        \"DbClusterResourceId\": \"cluster-E3ICGSCJRPWDY7NRQTELXFCKTQ\", ", 
            "        \"DBClusterMembers\": [], ", 
            "        \"Port\": 27017, ", 
            "        \"StorageEncrypted\": false, ", 
            "        \"AssociatedRoles\": [], ", 
            "        \"DBClusterParameterGroup\": \"default.docdb3.6\", ", 
            "        \"AvailabilityZones\": [", 
            "            \"us-east-1a\", ", 
            "            \"us-east-1b\", ", 
            "            \"us-east-1c\"", 
            "        ], ", 
            "        \"DBClusterArn\": \"arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:570346948435:cluster:vce-docdb-tst4\"", 
            "    }",
```

I am trying to use below filter to get value of Endpoint:
**stdout_lines.DBCluster.Endpoint**

Comment: what output or error do you get when you try with  stdout_lines.DBCluster.Endpoint, please paste the playbook as well

Comment: - name: Create AWS DocumentDB Cluster with AWS CLI
  command: >
    aws --region {{aws.region}} docdb create-db-cluster \
          --backup-retention-period 1 \
          --db-cluster-identifier docdb-tst3 \
          --db-subnet-group-name sg-45678 \
          --tags Key="Role",Value="DocumentDB" \
          --engine docdb \
          --deletion-protection true \
          --master-username docdbmstr \
          --master-user-password docdbpwd 
register: aws_docdbinfo

Comment: I am using above ansible task to create a Doc-DB cluster and storing the value on a variable. When I try printing variable I am getting below error  ***fatal: [8.8.8.8]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'DBCluster'***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is the json object which have to be piped through [from_json](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) filter. Simple test:

```
- hosts: masters
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - shell: /root/ansible/test.sh
    register: result
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.stdout | from_json).DBCluster.Endpoint }}"
```

Test data:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '{'
echo '"DBCluster": {'
echo '"Endpoint": "value1"'
echo '}, "key2": "value2"'
echo '}'
```

Comment: It works Much thanks for the explanation of from_json filter.